# Kafka consuming same messge multiple times

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am queuing a single message in kafka queue.

Kafka Prop :

```
enable.auto.commit=true
auto.commit.interval.ms=5000
max.poll.interval.ms=30000
```

Processing of my message was taking around 10mins. So message was keep on processing after every 5 mins.

Then I have changed the prop `max.poll.interval.ms` to 20 mins. Now the issue is fixed.
But my question is this : why is this happening. Since I already have auto commit enabled and it should happen every 5sec, then why my messages are not marked committed in the former case

Comment: 10 mins for a single message? That's crazy.

Comment: Yes. It sends notification to multiple users, it process all data,

Comment: Hmm. It would make more sense to have one message per notification/user rather than having a single message with all notifications/users.

Comment: What is the value of `auto.commit.interval.ms`?

Comment: auto.commit.interval.ms=5000

Comment: Maybe you should send messages to something like SNS instead, which is more suited for notifications than Kafka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`, then the largest offset is committed every `auto.commit.interval.ms` of time. However, this happens only whenever `poll()` is called. In every poll and in your case every 20mins (`max.poll.interval.ms`), the `enable.auto.commit` is checked. Whenever you `poll()`, the consumer checks if it is time to commit the offsets it returned in the last poll.

Now in your case, `poll()` is called every 20 minutes which means that it might even take up to additional 20 minutes (+5000ms) before committing the offset.

Comment: What if auto,commit is set to false? I have checked that, after the message processing, the offset is getting committed automatically? How it is possible

Comment: If you set `enable.auto.commit` to `false` then you must commit the offsets manually.

Comment: @AnkitBansal Yes, if the offset is not committed it will be re-consumed when the consumer is up and running again. In case the consumer is closed (without failing), the offset will be committed before exiting.